# Databricks: Migrate a registered model from one workspace to another?

Tags: azure, machine-learning, migration, databricks, mlflow

We have multiple Databricks Workspaces on Azure. On one of them we trained multiple models and registered them in the MLflow registry. Our goal is to move those model from one databricks workspace to another and so far, i could not find a straight forwared way to do this except running the training script again on the new databricks workspace.

Downloading the model an registering them in the new workspace didn't work so far. Should I create a "dummy" training script, that just loads the model, does nothing with it and then logs it away in the new workspace?

Seems to me like databricks never anticipated, that someone might want to migrate ML models?

Answer (score 1):

The model registry caches the model-related artifacts in the registry. So the shared model registry will have a copy of all these artifacts - MLmodel, conda.yaml, etc. from the source workspace. The actual run is not cached on the shared registry. Instead there is a pointer to the source run in the "run_link" field of a model version.

The mlflow-export-import tool uses the public MLflow API to do best effort migration. For OSS MLflow it works quite well. For Databricks MLflow the main limitation is that we cannot export notebook revisions associated with an MLflow run since there is no API endpoint for this. For registered models, it can migrate the run associated with the model subject to above caveat.

https://github.com/amesar/mlflow-export-import#registered-models-1

Answer (score 0):

You can use MLflow APIs for that, for example [Python Tracking API](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/index.html), with `get_registered_model`, `get_run`, `create_registered_model`, etc. One of the Databricks solution architect developed a [project for exporting and importing models/experiments/runs](https://github.com/amesar/mlflow-export-import) on top of the MLflow APIs.

You can also consider use of the [shared mflow registry](https://docs.databricks.com/applications/machine-learning/manage-model-lifecycle/multiple-workspaces.html) (sometimes is called central model registry) - when the training happens in specific workspace, but models are logged (optionally) and registered in central place - in this model it could be easier to maintain permissions, do backups, etc.